databricks JSONPath wildcard is missing results
I have a json structure that I am trying to match all the cpe_match nodes for, using a JSONPath expression.
Using databricks sql, I have the following query, where "nodes" contains my json:
    select to_json(nodes):[*].cpe_match
    from cve_raw

This results in

[[]]

Evaluating $.[*].cpe_match against the JSON correctly finds the 3 matches. Why does databricks give a different result? What am I doing wrong?
example json:
[
   {
  "children":[
     {
        "children":[
           
        ],
        "cpe_match":[
           {
              "cpe23Uri":"cpe:2.3:a:paloaltonetworks:cortex_xdr_agent:*:*:*:*:critical_environment:*:*:*",
              "cpe_name":[
                 
              ],
              "versionEndExcluding":"7.5.101",
              "versionEndIncluding":null,
              "versionStartIncluding":"7.5",
              "vulnerable":true,
              "versionStartExcluding":null
           }
        ],
        "operator":"OR"
     },
     {
        "children":[
           
        ],
        "cpe_match":[
           {
              "cpe23Uri":"cpe:2.3:o:microsoft:windows:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
              "cpe_name":[
                 
              ],
              "versionEndExcluding":null,
              "versionEndIncluding":null,
              "versionStartIncluding":null,
              "vulnerable":false,
              "versionStartExcluding":null
           }
        ],
        "operator":"OR"
     }
  ],
  "cpe_match":[
     
  ],
  "operator":"AND"

}
]

The [*] expression identifies all nodes in an array. It does not represent an "any property wildcard". I've simplified your JSON some to show what it is doing:
DECLARE OR REPLACE VARIABLE sample_json STRING DEFAULT 
'[
   {
      "children":
      [
        {
          "children":[],
          "cpe_match":["1"]
        },
        {
          "children":[],
          "cpe_match":["2"]
        }
      ],
      "cpe_match":["3"]   
    } 
]';

select 
  sample_json:[*].cpe_match, --[["3"]]
  sample_json:[*].children[*].cpe_match --[[["1"],["2"]]]

I don't know if it was intentional, but you have cpe_match at different levels in the JSON structure. If you're trying to do some more wildcard match of any property with name cpe_match, I don't think that is possible with Databrick's JSON path expressions.

yeah, that's intentional and exactly what I'm trying to do! I'll look for another method

Also, Databricks doesn't support recursive CTEs. I was thinking that might be a way to accomplish your goal, but it can't be done using Databricks SQL (supposedly there are python/scala workarounds).
